# Exclusive responsibility of a DCE

Tags: terminology, data

I've read a lot of definitions of DCE and DTE and I'd want to know if data transmission if exclusive responsibility of a DCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the actual function of the DCE ? , that is to provide ***clock rate*** to the DTE on the ***SERIAL link*** . This type of communications between two routers called (back to back routers connection) and could be between router on your site (your ownership) and other in ISP ownership,
So answer of your questions is YES, DCE is responsible on the data transferee but only on the ***serial interface***, on any other tybe of connection (ethernet) DCE has no control on the data transferee.